# handleSumbit function is not working in React Native application using React-Hook-Form and yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, validation, react-hook-form

all,
I am using React-hook-form and yup as my validation tool in my react native project. But currently, I encountered an issue which is the handleSubmit function is not working in my ResetPasswordScreen component. And I cannot figure out why(in LoginScreen which has similar logic and it works fine). I appreciate it if anyone can help.

Here is my execution flow in ResetPasswordScreen, input email -> pass validation -> other inputs are displayed. And I am using isCodeSent param to control if other inputs are shown or not. Here is the PasswordResetScreen code

```js
function PasswordResetScreen() {

  const [isCodeSent, setIsCodeSent] = useState(false)
  

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    clearErrors,
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    resolver: resetPwResolver,
  })

  

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log('onSubmit ========> ', data)

    if (isCodeSent) {
      // api call to submit reset request...
    } else {
      // api call to sent code here...
      
      //after sent code successfully, set isCodeSent param value as true to display the rest inputs
      setIsCodeSent(true)
    }
  }

  const dismissKeyboard = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss()
  }

  console.log('render foget pw page =====>', isCodeSent)
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={dismissKeyboard}>
      <View style={styles.passwordResetContainer}>
        <Text style={[globalStyles.label]}>
          {isCodeSent ? '' : 'A passcode will be sent to your email'}
        </Text>
        
        <Controller
          control={control}
          render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              onBlur={onBlur}
              onChangeText={onChange}
              value={value}
              placeholder='Email'
            />
          )}
          name='email'
        />
        <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>
          {errors.email ? errors.email.message : ''}
        </Text>

        {/* if code is sent, other inputs will be displayed */}
        {isCodeSent ? (
          <>
            <Text>isCodeSent-----{isCodeSent}</Text>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  placeholder='Passcode'
                />
              )}
              name='passcode'
            />
            <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>
              {errors.passcode ? errors.passcode.message : ''}
            </Text>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  placeholder='New Password'
                />
              )}
              name='newPassword'
            />
            <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>
              {errors.newPassword ? errors.newPassword.message : ''}
            </Text>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  placeholder='Confirm Password'
                />
              )}
              name='confirmPassword'
            />
            <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>
              {errors.confirmPassword ? errors.confirmPassword.message : ''}
            </Text>
            
          </>
        ) : null}
        <Button
          btnText={isCodeSent ? 'Submit' : 'Send'}
          onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}

export default PasswordResetScreen
```

here is the code of validation part :

```js
   // all the reg are defined before
const resetPwSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .matches(emailReg, 'Invalid email format')
    .required(),
  passcode: yup
    .string()
    .matches(passcodeReg, 'Invalid passcode format')
    .required(),
  newPassword: yup
    .string()
    .matches(passwordReg, 'Password must between 6 to 12 digits')
    .required(),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .matches(passwordReg, 'Password must between 6 to 12 digits')
    .required(),
})
export const resetPwResolver = yupResolver(resetPwSchema)
```

So, the code in onSubmit function 'console.log('onSubmit ========> ', data)' is not output at the console, which means the handleSubmit function is not working. Also this 'console.log('render foget pw page =====>', isCodeSent)' shows isCodeSend value is false all the time, which indicates the handleSubmit is not working.

I am thinking is it because I break the form into two parts but that does not make sense. I really cannot figure out what is the reason. If anyone can help, that would be so great.

Comment: Have you tried to log errors object? Maybe it can't pass validation

Comment: My god, thanks for your hint, I output the whole errors object, then figure out the reason and found the solution. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for that and figure out the reason for this behavior. The solution is: to define two schemas, one is for only the email field, another schema will include all the files (email, passcode, password, confirmPassword).
Here is my new code for schema:

```js
const resetPwEmailSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .matches(emailReg, 'Invalid email format')
    .required(requiredErrMsg('Email')),
})
export const resetPwEmailResolver = yupResolver(resetPwEmailSchema)

const resetPwSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .matches(emailReg, 'Invalid email format')
    .required(requiredErrMsg('Email')),
  passcode: yup
    .string()
    .matches(passcodeReg, 'Invalid passcode format')
    .required(requiredErrMsg('Passcode')),
  newPassword: yup
    .string()
    .matches(passwordReg, 'Password must between 6 to 12 digits')
    .required(requiredErrMsg('Password')),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .matches(passwordReg, 'Password must between 6 to 12 digits')
    .required(requiredErrMsg('Password')),
})
export const resetPwResolver = yupResolver(resetPwSchema)
```

The reason why this happen is when hit 'SEND' button, all the fields will be validated because the schema includes all fields(even other hidden fields), but except email field, other fields are empty(they are not shown), so the validation will fail, so the onSubmit function will never be run.